# What training pattern should I use to develop V-sit and V-hang?

Tags: gymnastics, conditioning, bodyweight

I would like to acquire a V-sit and V-hang (from a neutral vertical hang; without chest or shoulder assistance). I can hold a passable L-sit for 5-10 seconds on parallettes, but not from a hang (although I can hold one better at the top of a pull-up). I may be missing some technical points when executing the L-hang given how it lags behind.

I have a fairly clear idea of progressions to develop the L-sit (such as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gc0-uVMGCSM)), but what I'm less clear on is what pattern of training to apply; rounds, repetitions, days, and so on.

I'd also welcome suggestions for exercises. My current plan was to focus on holding a tuck and then partially extend the legs as possible. With a view to Vs I wonder how I should attempt to train that range of motion, since my legs never go past the horizontal at the moment I wonder whether I will actually progress towards the V without some elastic bands or a partner to support the legs, even if I improve my Ls?

The sort of answer I'm looking for is of the form: "X seconds every Y days of L-sit/tuck/lifts." I'd like to push this fairly hard.

Comment: Do you want the L or the V? You mention both. I suggest rephrasing the question (primarily the title) to ask about progressions to the V-seat; they'll likely involve working on the L-seat a lot (but I don't know, as I can't do it either and I'd like to know!). +1 in any case.

Comment: The ultimate goal is Vs, to which end I see good Ls as an intermediate aim. Updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't focus on precisely those exercises, but you might want to check out [Building the Gymnastic Body](http://www.gymnasticbodies.com/), which has exercise progressions that incorporate both the V-sit and the V-hang.  The emphasis is a little different, but the exercise progressions may still get you what you need.  The book isn't as detailed as what you want in terms of "X number of seconds," but there is plenty of room in there to push yourself to keep trying for the next level.

In the book, the V-hang is used as part of an obliques exercise on the way to doing side-lever pulls. For the V-sit  the book has progressions for increasingly difficult V-ups, manna, and leg lifts.